# C++ Numerical truncation error

Tags: c++, truncation, numerical-computing

sorry if dumb but could not find an answer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double a(0);
double b(0.001);
cout << a - 0.0 << endl;
for (;a<1.0;a+=b);
cout << a - 1.0 << endl;
for (;a<10.0;a+=b);
cout << a - 10.0 << endl;
cout << a - 10.0-b << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Output:
0
6.66134e-16
0.001
-1.03583e-13

Tried compiling it with MSVC9, MSVC10, Borland C++ 2010. All of them arrive in the end to the error of about 1e-13.
Is it normal to have such a significant error accumulation over only a 1000, 10000 increments?

Comment: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#[[A%20matter%20of%20precision]] (not me, heh)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is normal numeric representation floating point error.  It has to do with the fact that the hardware must approximate most floating point numbers, rather than storing them exactly.  Thus, the compiler you use should not matter.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks, I do understand truncation error and all the other crap. Done a lot of theoretical work on numerical methods but I just never checked it myself and was very surprised to find out how large it is...

Comment: Well, a double gives you roughly 16 decimal digits of precision, that that's about right.  When you loop 1000 times, you're down to 13 or so digits of precision.

Comment: Mind that it's particularly painful only with irrational (in base 2) numbers.  If you use powers of two you'll be fine.  E.g. if your adder was 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, etc., they will eventually add up *exactly* to 1.0, as these values in base 2 are 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, and 0.0001.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang Good point, though I'd argue if you're doing that sort of thing, you might be better off fitting into integer arithmetic.

Comment: @ WhirlWind: somewhere deep in my heart I was expecting it to accumulate slower than linearly due to randomness of the error nature but now I realize that was just a fantasy :)

Comment: Well if you've got a fixed number of decimal places, integers will always win.  E.g. don't compute US Dollars in floating point, represent it in integers where 1 is one cent or maybe some fraction of a cent.

Answer (score 2):

This is why when using a floating point error you should never do:

```
if( foo == 0.0 ){
    //code here
}
```

and instead do

```
bool checkFloat(float _input, float _compare, float _epsilon){
    return ( _input + _epsilon > _compare ) && ( _input - _epsilon < _compare );
}
```

Comment: Checking against zero is fine in many circumstances as it can be exactly represented in the hardware, but of course it depends on what you're doing with it...  Starting at 1 and subtracting .1 ten times will not lead to 0, of course.

Comment: That's very true but in most cases it's just not good practice.  I like erring on the side of caution.

Comment: erring on the side of caution... funny ;)  Or perhaps erring under the size of epsilon.

Answer (score 2):

think about this.  every operation introduces slight error, but next operation uses slightly faulty result.  given enough iterations, you will deviate from true result.  if you like, write your expressions in the form `t0 = (t + y + e), t1 =  (t0 + y +e)` and figure out terms with epsilon.  from their terms you can estimate approximate error.

there is also second source of error:  at some point you are combining relatively small and relatively large numbers, towards the end.  if you recall definition of machine precision, `1 + e = 1`, at some point operations will be losing significant bits.

Hopefully this helps to clarify in laymen terms

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with floating point numbers—they're approximate, and weird things happen at zero (that is, weird representations appear).  Because of this, some of the operations on numbers you take for granted have to be handled more delicately.

When comparing two numbers, you can't simply say `a == b` because one might be `0` and the other `-1.03583e-13` due to the loss of precision along the floating point operations applied to get to `a` and `b`.  You have to choose an arbitrary tolerance, like this: `fabs(a,b) < 1e-8`.

When printing a number, you often need to limit the number of digits printed.  If you use `printf`, you can say `printf("%g\n", a);`, which won't print things like `-1.03583e-13` .  I don't know if there's an `iostream` analog to `%g`; is there?